# AlarmManager as a service, how can I get the set alarm to repeat?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have multiple AlarmManagers inside of a Service class. I set each AlarmManager to a different time and I can get it to repeat using setRepeating(). I start my service from an Activity. Ok, now for my real question.

Everyday, these times set change. And in my activity, I get a new instance of these timings (not modifying it directly, but by doing a series of calculations i.e. calling a method). And by getting a new instance of different times, I want to know how I can be able to update and restart the Alarm service with these new times, even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    }
    public void startAlarm(View view) {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 3000; // 3 seconds

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Log.e("System.currentTime", "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(View view) {
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

and this is your AlarmReceiver

```
/**
 * Created by Techno Blogger on 1/2/17.
 */

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

and do remember to mention this in your Manifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```